# Manipulating a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Still a beginner in R and would appreciate any help with two questions about manipulating a dataframe `df` that is structured like this:

```
structure(list(country = c("Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "France", 
"France", "France"), date = structure(c(18353, 18354, 18355, 
18353, 18354, 18355), class = "Date"), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), share = c(0.00480432389150235, 0.00576122906219994, 0.00577170418006431, 
0.0883595235712141, 0.0959849212276397, 0.104823151125402), max_share = c(0.110235379599597, 
0.110235379599597, 0.110235379599597, 0.122052589288188, 0.122052589288188, 
0.122052589288188)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

(1) The variable `max_share` is the maximum `share` for each `country` observed between the initial `date` and end `date`. I came up with a rather clumsy way to add this variable into the `df` and was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Here's what I did:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarize(max_share=max(share)) %>%
  select(country, max_share)

df <- merge(df, df1, all=TRUE, by.x="country",by.y="country")
```

(2) I would like to create within the existing `df` two subgroups as follows.

I would like to add a second group variable called `selection`. I would like to pick those countries where `max_share>0.10` and attribute for them the value `1` to `selection`.

Next, I would like to add to the `df` another `country` called `Rest of the world`. The `Rest of the world` observation will be labelled `2` under `selection`. Note that we will have several new observations as we have multiple dates for `Rest of the world`.

And then the bit I was struggling with. I would like that the `share` for these new observations is calculated as the sum of the share of the other countries under `selection == 1`.

I tried `summarise` and `aggregate` but could not identify how to keep the row at the same dimension, change the values for the non-numeric variables and only sum the numeric ones. There's probably a simple way to do this. Just couldn't figure it out.

In the end the df would contain the original set of countries, a new set of rows for the new observation `Rest of the world` (1 new row for each date), and a new column for the variable called `selection`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should shared reproducible data. A picture of your data does not help. Try sharing the output of `dput(head(df))`

Comment: Have done so, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr::case_when` and `dplyr::replace_na`:

```
df2<-structure(list(country = c("Rest of the world", "Rest of the world", "Rest of the world"), date = structure(c(18353, 18354, 18355), class = "Date"), group = c(1, 1, 1), share = c(NA,NA,NA)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
df %>%
  bind_rows(df2) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(max_share=max(share),
         selection=case_when(max_share > 0.10 & country != "Rest of the world" ~ 1,
                             country=="Rest of the world" ~ 2,
                             TRUE~0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(share=replace_na(max_share,sum(share[selection==1])))
```

Resulting df:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 6
  country           date       group   share max_share selection
  <chr>             <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Brazil            2020-04-01     1 0.00577   0.00577         0
2 Brazil            2020-04-02     1 0.00577   0.00577         0
3 Brazil            2020-04-03     1 0.00577   0.00577         0
4 France            2020-04-01     1 0.105     0.105           1
5 France            2020-04-02     1 0.105     0.105           1
6 France            2020-04-03     1 0.105     0.105           1
7 Rest of the world 2020-04-01     1 0.289    NA               2
8 Rest of the world 2020-04-02     1 0.289    NA               2
9 Rest of the world 2020-04-03     1 0.289    NA               2
```

With `df2` being:

```
            country       date group share
1 Rest of the world 2020-04-01     1    NA
2 Rest of the world 2020-04-02     1    NA
3 Rest of the world 2020-04-03     1    NA
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. One follow-up question though: my actual df has about 140 time observations. Is there quick short-cut to specify df2 for this larger dataset? Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome, don't hesitate to validate the question if you are satisfied. Regarding the short cut, what do you mean exactly? if you have the df on a csv file there should be no problem?

Comment: Probably an elementary issue - still learning R. The cvs file I have corresponds to the df in the second line of your answer. The first one, df2, requires manually typing 140 times "Rest of the world" along with the dates. 140 is the number of days in the data set, and this number changes every day as the data set is updated daily. So I am looking for a way to write this differently. Is there an easy way to define df2 based on df (so I dont need to redefine the structure) and rename the observation for country as "Rest of the world"?

Comment: Okay. You can use something like `rep("Rest of the world",140)`, and `seq.Date(from=,to=)`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(max_share = max(share)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregate to make your 'selection'

```
df$selection <- df$country %in% with(aggregate(share ~ country, data = df, FUN = max), country[share > 0.1]))

  country       date group       share selection
1  Brazil 2020-04-01     1 0.004804324         0
2  Brazil 2020-04-02     1 0.005761229         0
3  Brazil 2020-04-03     1 0.005771704         0
4  France 2020-04-01     1 0.088359524         1
5  France 2020-04-02     1 0.095984921         1
6  France 2020-04-03     1 0.104823151         1
```